# Deformations using the Bayes' theorem

Tags: bayes-theorem

I couldn't do the following deformations using the Bayes' theorem:
$$p(\phi|x,\eta) = \frac{p(\phi,x|\eta)}{p(x|\eta)} = \frac{p(x|\phi)p(\phi|\eta)}{p(x|\eta)}$$
I can understand that the first deformation can be done by $p(\phi| x, \eta) \cdot p(x|\eta) = p(\phi, x | \eta)$, but I couldn't figure out how to bring the third from the second.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your situation, this holds :$$p(\phi,x|\eta) = p(x, \phi|\eta) = p(x|\phi)p(\phi|\eta)$$